# Compressed camera images from rosbag to matlab

Tags: rosbag, compressedimage, best-practices, rosmatlab, compressed-image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file containing lots of sensor messages, including compressed camera images. I would like to use this stream of camera images in MATLAB.

I know of two possible approaches: either by exporting all images to JPG and load those into MATLAB, or by using [ROSMATLAB](http://www.mathworks.nl/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html).

I think that the first approach would involve creating a Python script to collect the camera images form the `image_transport` node `republish`. This seems to involve an awful lot of decompressing and compressing (when saving back to JPG), so I'm looking for a way to directly collect the images from the bag file and save those. I believe that the compressed images in the bag file are JPG compressed, so it should be possible to directly map them.

The second approach would also involve the `republish` node, I think, since ROSMATLAB does not yet seem to support image transport. Also, I've run into problems collecting the images on the subscriber. I've seen [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ros-sig-matlab/y8xaZ_OWNlM/Vj2CKvc7O0QJ) great tutorial on creating an image publisher, but I found it hard to reverse it. I've also seen [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/164831/depth-image-stream-from-kinect-in-matlab-with-ros-io-package/) question on ROS answers, which does a good job showing some of the basics, but I couldn't replicate it.

Long story short: can anyone provide a best practice to manage images from a rosbag in MATLAB?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193914/compressed-camera-images-from-rosbag-to-matlab/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [matlab_rosbag](https://github.com/bcharrow/matlab_rosbag) to open the file. Then just load the topic you want and fwrite the topic data to a jpg file. This will generate a normal jpg file which you can then view/edit in matlab using imread.

Now if only we could convert from jpg in memory to plain RGB...

---

Originally posted by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) with karma: 230 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-10-10**:
I have written the entire data part from the `matlab_rosbag` image structure as a binary file called "image.jpg". Next, I loaded that using `imread`, giving me a valid MATLAB image. This is undoubtedly slow, using a lot of hard drive writing, but it gets me somewhere. Thanks!

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-10-10**:
You can do it without saving to the harddrive using the code sequence discussed in this thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157391-how-to-convert-a-cell-array-into-an-image.